# Form Wont Submit

Tags: html, forms

I've been searching for hours and can't find out whats wrong with my code. I click the submit button and it wont submit. If I put a closing div at the end of the first opening form tag then it will submit, but everything is out of place. Please please help!

```
<form action="../home" method="post">
<table class="position-details" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="jobTitle" style="padding-top:10px;">Job title</label></td>
    <td>
        <input id="jobTitle" name="jobTitle" required="required" size="60" type="text"/><br>
      Example: “Rails Programmer”
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-top: 4px;"><label>Category</label></td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 0;">
      <ul class="category selectable_container" style="list-style: none;">

          <li class="selectable selected">
            <input checked="checked" id="Programming" name="listing[category_id]" onclick="$(this).fire(&quot;selectable:changed&quot;);" type="radio" value="Programming">
            <label for="Programming">Programming</label>
          </li>

          <li class="selectable">
            <input id="Design" name="listing[category_id]" onclick="$(this).fire(&quot;selectable:changed&quot;);" type="radio" value="Design">
            <label for="Design">Design</label>
          </li>

          <li class="selectable">
            <input id="Business" name="listing[category_id]" onclick="$(this).fire(&quot;selectable:changed&quot;);" type="radio" value="Business">
            <label for="Business">Business</label>
          </li>

          <li class="selectable">
            <input id="SystemAdmin" name="listing[category_id]" onclick="$(this).fire(&quot;selectable:changed&quot;);" type="radio" value="SystemAdmin">
            <label for="SystemAdmin">System Admin</label>
          </li>

          <li class="selectable">
            <input id="Copywriter" name="listing[category_id]" onclick="$(this).fire(&quot;selectable:changed&quot;);" type="radio" value="Copywriter">
            <label for="Copywriter">Copywriter</label>
          </li>

          <li class="selectable">
            <input id="Customer" name="listing[category_id]" onclick="$(this).fire(&quot;selectable:changed&quot;);" type="radio" value="Customer">
            <label for="Customer">Customer Service/Support</label>
          </li>

          <li class="selectable">
            <input id="Miscellaneous" name="listing[category_id]" onclick="$(this).fire(&quot;selectable:changed&quot;);" type="radio" value="Miscellaneous">
            <label for="Miscellaneous">Miscellaneous</label>
          </li>

      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="jobHeadquarters" style="padding-top:10px;">Headquarters</label></td>
    <td>
      <input id="jobHeadquarters" name="jobHeadquarters" required="required" size="60" type="text"><br>
      “Chicago, IL”, “Stockholm, Sweden”
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="jobApply" style="padding-top:10px;">How To Apply</label></td>
    <td>
      <input id="jobApply" name="jobApply" required="required" size="60" type="text"/><br>
      “resumes@company.com” or "http://company.com"
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>

<div class="position-description">
  <p><label for="jobDescription">Job description</label></p>
  <div class="rich_text_area uses_div">
    <div class="text_area">
      <div id="listing_description_editor" class="editor" contenteditable="true" style="height:250px;"></div>
      <input class="body" id="jobDescription" name="jobDescription" required="required" type="hidden"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h2 style="font-family:FuturaBT-Book;">Company Details</h2>

<table class="company-details">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="companyName">Name</label></td>
    <td>
      <input id="companyName" name="companyName" required="required" size="60" type="text"/><br>Enter your company or organization’s name.
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="companyUrl">URL</label></td>
    <td>
      <input id="companyUrl" name="companyUrl" size="60" type="text"/><br>
      Example: http://www.google.com
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="companyEmail">Email</label></td>
    <td>
      <input id="companyEmail" name="companyEmail" required="email" size="60" type="text"/><br>
      This is where we’ll send your receipt and confirmation email.
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>

  <h2>Help your ad stand out</h2>

  <div class="highlight-listing">
    <p>For only <strong>$50 more</strong> you can highlight your ad. Highlighted ads have a yellow background in the list so they stand out against the others.</p>
    <p>
      <input name="listing[highlight]" type="hidden" value="0"><input id="listing_highlight" name="listing[highlight]" type="checkbox" value="1">
      <label for="listing_highlight"><strong>Yes, highlight my ad</strong> for only $50.</label>
    </p>
  </div>
  <button value="Send" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="submit"/></form>
```

I'm rendering the above code in a partial. It goes into this:

```
  <div class="header-new-post">
    <div class="header-new-post-container">
      <div class="topstatus">
        <ul>
          <li class="new">1. Create your ad</li>
          <li class="preview">2. Preview</li>
          <li class="purchase" style="margin-right: 0;">3. Purchase and publish</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="create-header">
    <div class="create-info">
      <p>Your job listing will remain on this site for 30 days. After 30 days your job listing will expire and be removed. You can always post the job again for $100 for another 30 days.</p>
    </div>
    <h1>Step 1: Create your Ad</h1>
  </div>

<div class="theFormItself" style="padding-left: 70px;">
  <%= render 'home/submitpartial' %>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Where is ending tag of <form..> ?

Comment: I coudnt see the </form> please add that and check, It will work I hope

Comment: For reference, the closing `form` tag didn't show up as it was only preceded by 3 spaces, so it wasn't seen as a code block, so the parser ate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<input type="submit">
```

Comment: `<button type="submit"` and `<input type="submit"` are functionally equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But this did not fix it either

Comment: your code is working fine. Can you please send me complete html code on your page. I mean from <html> to </html>

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/u6ujedym/

this is work
also

```
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="submit" >Send</button>
```

Comment: check your page encoding, try it without BOM